# prevent vim preview window from closing

Tags: vim

I have the following in my .vimrc alongside of neocomplete

```
set completeopt+=preview,longest,menuone
```

The preview window opens automatically for me as expected, however when I hit enter on a line of neocomplete or I start a parenthesis of a command (eg "foo.Bar(") the preview window closes and I have to remember all of the arguments that went with it.

I would like the preview window to stay open permanently or until I close foo.Bar()

Comment: What you want is the default behavior: the preview window is only closed explicitly with `:pclose` or `<C-w>z`. You will have to read neocomplete's doc again or ask on their issue tracker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behaviour of neocomplete is to auto-close the preview window but it is configurable. Add this to your .vimrc:

```
let g:neocomplete#enable_auto_close_preview = 0
```

You will need to manually close the preview window with `:pclose` or `<C-w>z`

See [`:h neocomplete.txt`](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim/blob/master/doc/neocomplete.txt)